# Laravel [5.4] TokenMismatchException in Parked Domain

Tags: php, laravel, appdomain

I am using Laravel 5.4 with 3 parked domain on top of the main application. 
The requirement is to have multiple domains parked on the same application and load the data based on the domain. 
I am able to load data as per requirements, however, when I try to post a form the application throws TokenMismatchException. I am using Laravel's Auth  to log in and every attempt or Post operation ends up to the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by it being a cross site request. Disabling CSRF middleware will solve this issue, but is not recommended.

Add URIs that you want to exclude from CSRF verification to the `$except` array in the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.